# OpenCV 2.4.3 VideoCapture is not working

Tags: opencv, video-capture

Recently I migrated to `OpenCV 2.4.3` from `OpenCV 2.4.1`.

My program which worked well with `2.4.1` version now encounters problem with `2.4.3`.

The problem is related to `VideoCapture` that can not open my video file.

I saw a similar problem while searching the internet, but I couldn't find a proper solution for this. Here is my sample code:

```
VideoCapture video(argv[1]);
while(video.grab())
{
    video.retrieve(imgFrame);
    imshow("Video",ImgFrame);
    waitKey(1);
}
```

It's worth mentioning that capturing video from webcam device works well, but I want to grab stream from file.

I'm using `QT Creator 5` and I compiled `OpenCV` with `MinGW`. I'm using Windows.

I tried several different video formats and I rebuilt `OpenCV` with and without `ffmpeg`, but the problem still persists.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
VideoCapture video(argv[1]);
int delay = 1000.0/video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
while(1)
{
    if ( !video.read(ImgFrame)) break;
    imshow("Video",ImgFrame);
    waitKey(delay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with OpenCV I struggled using IP cams until my mentor discovered how to get them to work, don't forget to plug your IP address in otherwise it won't work!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request

# Sets up the webcam and connects to it and initalizes a variable we use for it
stream=urllib.request.urlopen('http://xx.x.x.xx/mjpg/video.mjpg')
bytes=b''

while True:
    # Takes frames from the camera that we can use
    bytes+=stream.read(16384)
    a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        frame = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = frame[0:400, 0:640] # Camera dimensions [0:WIDTH, 0:HEIGHT]

       # Displays the final product
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)

     # Hit esc to kill
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```